# I just installed evans debugger and when i click the program it never opens

Tags: linux

I just installed evans debugger and when i click the program it never opens. im running suse linux 11.1.The program installs fine and shows up in my menu but never opens

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you tried debugging it via a Terminal window?

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug it the naïve way:

1. Open up **Terminal**.
2. Find the name of the executable that links to your debugger (editing the menu entry might show you the command that is run when you click on the menu item).
3. Run this command via Terminal.
4. Post the output so that we can actually see what's making the program not work.

Comment: The command is just edb and when i type it into terminal i get  Starting EDB Version: 0.9.16 
Please Report Bugs & Requests At: http://bugs.codef00.com/
Segmentation fault